# How to parse json using ajax script in ESP32 app

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, parsing, esp32

I am working on a project using ESP32, I get some data from some sensors  and send it to a webpage hosted in the same board.
I read some info on the web and understood that is "better" to send all data from several sensors using json method, so my function to get and send data is this:

```
 void handle_leituras()
{
  String results_json = "{ \"data\": " + Data +
                         "," + "\"hora\": " + Hora +
                         "," + "\"temp_amb1\": " + Tout + " }";

  server.send(200, "application/json", results_json);

}
```

Testing above function in serial monitor I have this data:

```
{"data": Domingo, 12/4/2020,"hora": 20:53,"temp_amb1": 25.75}
```

I found a script that can get only one data and print it on that page, this is the script:

```
    function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("DATA").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "leituras", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Its my index page code that shows data on webpage:

```
const char pag_inicial[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">
<title>My 1st test</title></head>
<html>
<body>

<div id="pagina">
<h1>System XPTO</h1>

<div>
    Data: <span id="DATA">ND</span><br>
    Hora: <span id="HORA">ND</span><br>
    Temperatura Ambiente: <span id="TEMPAMB1">ND</span>
</div>

<div id="botoes">
    <button type="button" onclick="sendData(0)" style="width: 80px; height: 30px; margin: 30px;">ON</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="sendData(1)" style="width: 80px; height: 30px; margin: 30px;">OFF</button><BR>
</div>
<script>
setInterval(function() {
  // Call a function repetatively with 1 Second interval
  getData();
}, 1000); //2000mSeconds update rate

//function to set on / off a LED on my board
function sendData(led) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("LEDState").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "setLED?LEDstate="+led, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "leituras", true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("DATA").innerHTML = jsonResponse.data;
      document.getElementById("HORA").innerHTML = jsonResponse.hora;
      document.getElementById("TEMPAMB1").innerHTML = jsonResponse.temp_amb1;
    }
    else {
      console.log(this.status);
    }
  };
}   
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
)=====";
```

My problem is...I don't know how to modify this script to get more sensors values from the described above function.
Anybody can save me please?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: from my project https://github.com/jandrassy/IsgModbusTcpSG/blob/master/IsgModbusTcpSG/data/script.js

Comment: Thanks Maxim, I really don't know how to prog in java/ajax....I saw your code and understood that its complete but I can't see how my code can be write based yours so sorry for my inexperience.
I forgot to show that in my html page I am getting data like this code:
<div id="infos">
 Data: <span id="DATA">ND</span><br>
        Hora: <span id="HORA">ND</span><br>
 Temperatura Ambiente: <span id="TEMPAMB1">ND</span>
</div>
Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `XMLHttpRequest` only supports `responseText` and `responseXML`, it does not support `responseJSON` property. However, as long as your server is sending a valid serialised JSON string, the `responseText` should contain the JSON code as text, so all you've got to do is to parse it with JSON.parse(), and then you can access each JSON element with dot notation:

```
function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "leituras", true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("DATA").innerHTML = jsonResponse.data;
      document.getElementById("HORA").innerHTML = jsonResponse.hora;
      document.getElementById("TEMPAMB1").innerHTML = jsonResponse.temp_amb1;
    }
    else {
      console.log(this.status);
    }
  };
}
```

This piece of code works for all browsers that supports `XMLHttpRequest` and `JSON` as long as the server is sending a valid JSON object.

Comment: Hey friend, thanks for that light! I just applied that tip here but no success. My function on  esp32 server is sending this data: {"data": Domingo, 12/4/2020,"hora": 20:53,"temp_amb1": 25.75} but on webpage I can't see that info.
At browser console I have this erros:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 9
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onload ((index):43)
xhttp.onload @ (index):43
load (async)
getData @ (index):41
(anonymous) @ (index):22
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):20

Comment: It means that your JSON is not a valid JSON object. Looking at `{"data": Domingo, 12/4/2020,"hora": 20:53,"temp_amb1": 25.75}`, the date token in your JSON object is missing a key, do you means to send data from server as `{"data": Domingo, "date": 12/4/2020,"hora": 20:53,"temp_amb1": 25.75}`?

Comment: you're right...if I understood a made a mistake, now the output is:
{"dia":Segunda,"data":13/4/2020,"hora":21:52,"temp_amb1":26.87} sould i put some space between some data into that info? thanks

Comment: I just test using an output like: '{"dia":Segunda,"data":13/4/2020,"hora":21:52,"temp_amb1":26.87}
at console we have this info:
GET http://192.168.1.230/leituras net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
getData @ (index):43
(anonymous) @ (index):24
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):22

Comment: Your JSON data looks different each time, you need to make sure what you send from server match what you want to decode. BTW, `{"dia":Segunda,"data":13/4/2020,"hora":21:52,"temp_amb1":26.87}` is still not a valid JSON, when you send string as a JSON value, you need to double-quote the string, so "dia": "Segunda" is correct JSON element. not "dia":Segunda. Please read more about [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_objects.asp), and use an online [JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)  to valid the json data you formatted on your server to ensure it is a valid one.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! you solved that problem! I will mark as solved and add all solution.